# PHP preg_match_all with Wordpress to echo a image if more than 1 image in post

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically what I am looking to accomplish is if there is more than 1 img it will echo the below statement so I can basically have a rollover saying click to see more. Another question would be how would I have it link to the post itself if I were to change it to 'a href' and echo out the permalink to post_id.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
function catch_images() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_image = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/ii', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_image = $matches [2] [0];
  if ($output == '2') {
  echo '<div class="seemore"><img src="images/magglass.png"></div><div class="seemoretext">See More</div>';
  }
}
```

Well I feel stupid, I should of just put the following:

```
if ($output > '2') {
```

Comment: what do you want it to do if it has 5,6 or 100 images ? echo the "see more" once ? and in that case, link to what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the answer to my own question, it will echo if there is more than 1 img src tag in a given post.

```
function catch_images() {
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_image = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/ii', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_image = $matches [0] [1];
  if ($output > '2') {
  echo '<div class="seemore"><div class="seemoreimg"><img src="images/magglass.png"></div><div class="seemoretext">See More</div></div>';
 }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485011/how-do-i-show-the-number-of-images-attached-to-a-post-on-the-image-attachment-pa) to check the number of attached images in your post? This assumes that your images are attached to your post, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, As said in comment , I did not really understood what you want to link if it has more than 2 images , to the image itself ?? to attachment page ? to another post ?
anyhow, something like this should work - read and execute the comments to suit your needs ..

(the second question I did not understood ...)

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'published', // or NULL
            //'post_mime_type' => 'image', // only if you want images alone
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

    $attachments = get_posts($args);


$counter = 0;
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
 if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        if (!$counter == 1) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID);
            }
        else {
        // uncomment the following line if you want a LIST of all following attachments and then delete the marked line
        //echo '<a href = ' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '> see more (image'. $counter .') </a>' ;
            }
    ++$counter;
    } 
      // Delete this line if you have more than 2 images, otherwise it will show the last one only
      echo '<a href = ' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '> see more (image'. $counter .') </a>' ;
 }
```

Comment: My apology I meant to the post itself

Comment: You mean you want the link of "see more" to go to the post itself ?

Comment: Thanks for your help I got it figured out